# Mining new private alt coin derived from litecoin

Tags: litecoin, altcoin, cgminer, altcoin-development

I have created an new private altcoin from litecoin(build on linux ubuntu) and it is working correctly. Now i want install any miner application (like cgminer) with CPU mining(for test). I have installed cgminer (Older version which support CPU mining) but miner not running and it always showing "No server could found exiting". Also i am confused with following doubts,

1. Can we mine coins with single node(Its my own private coin and it is installed only my pc)?
2. cgminer showing scrypt disabled(because its need OpenCL). Is scrypt only work with GPU?

Thanks In Advance,

Mufeed

Comment: There are scrypt cpu miners which may suffice in your case. I would think that you would need at least 2 nodes to test with, assuming you generated your own Genesis block you would want to test the consensus mechanism to make sure any changes you have made work.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not the most familiar with altcoins, but...

1. Yes, I'm pretty sure you can. Because basically you're mining blocks using the info from your node, so I don't see any harm. I've never tested this, because i'm too lazy and I don't see a point in making my own altcoin. So don't quote me on this.
2. Scrypt doesn't require OpenCL. If i'm not mistaken, OpenCL is mainly used to allow GPUs to mine.

Comment: Scrypt is an algorithm, and doesn't require any any specific sort of hardware to run.  It was designed to be "memory hard", meaning it requires a lot of memory in order to make it hard to do on procedures that don't have a fast bus to a lot of memory.  You don't need OpenCL or gpu processing at all.  If you aren't competing for blocks, and you just want to test, a cpu will be just fine.